# Prove that the cosine distance between any two vectors of 0’s and 1’s of the same length is at most 90 degrees.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

This is what I've figured so far.

[image: Cosine Similarity]

How do I proceed from here? I feel I'm close to the answer but I can't put it in mathematical terms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I don't see the anything to proceed...

Comment: $\theta\in[0,180^\circ]$. For what angles can you have $\cos(\theta)\geq0$?

Comment: 0 to 90, right? Do I have to specify the range of theta?

Comment: This is also visually clear, as both of the vectors are in the first orthant. Also, the requirement that the vectors have the same length is irrelevant (though one might want to require that they have nonzero length for purposes of defining the angle).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose vectors, $A = \{a_1, a_2,...,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2,...,b_n\}$

$CosineDis(A,B) = 1-CosineSim(A,B)=1- \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2}}$

If vectors $A$ and $B$ are of $0s$ and $1s$, then $0\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2}}\le1$ and

$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2}}=1$ iff $a_i=b_i=1$ where $1\le i\le n$

So, $0\le CosineDis(A,B) \le 1$ for the specific case of vectors. Hence, $0^\circ\le \theta \le 90^\circ $